# Firefox issue : Script Panel was inactive during page load

Tags: firefox

I downloaded latest firefox 14.0.1 & started getting "Script Panel was inactive during page load" and google to see resolution most of the site explains private browser feature.. after some research I found to disable private browsing itself from tools menu  (link given below)

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/921609

but still the I see "script panel is inactive" message. is there any resolution to this of I have to live with it... I even tried using other version for firebug but I still see the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the firebug options (triangle next to the bug) and enable "On for all web pages". I am sure this is not what you really want, but it does address the question.

Comment: I could not find "On for all web pages" option..  i am using firefox 14.0.1 7 firebug version is 1.10.1

Comment: @user593029 I am using FF 14.0.1, Firebug 1.10.0. The option is the dropdown menu next to the firebug button. You need to have "view->toolbars->navigation tool bar" enabled to see it.

Comment: I found it... i was looking below on firebug it is triangle is above,  right hand side corner.